# Connecting to MongoDB through VB.NET 2010

Tags: vb.net, mongodb

I am attempting to connect to a MongoDB database:

```
Dim server As MongoServer = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost")
Dim db As MongoDatabase = server("mydb")
Dim coll As MongoCollection = db("coll")

Dim query = New QueryDocument("name","sid")
Dim item As BsonDocument = coll.FindOneAs(query)
```

The last line throws an error, and reads:

> Public Overridable function FindOneAs(documentType As System.Type)As Object': Value of type MongoDB.driver.queryDocument cannot be converted to System.Type

Now I know that the object passed here is most probably of `Type`, but then I am not able to proceed. What should I pass instead of QueryDocument to execute my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the static methods of the `Query` class, like `EQ` which means equals. The other operators for MongoDb are also located on that class. You can find the details [here](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/?topic=html/2658e6c4-0b00-b2fc-bc2e-321e1676304a.htm).

```
Dim server As MongoServer = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost")
Dim db As MongoDatabase = server("mydb")
Dim coll As MongoCollection = db("coll")

Dim query = Query.EQ("name","sid")
Dim item As BsonDocument = coll.FindOneAs(query)
```

Comment: Thanks I figured I had to type cast the return value of FindOneAs function As BsonDocument.
I would try your method too.. :)